# Android search is never invoked

Tags: android

I am completely stuck and have spent hours reading possible solutions to this.
Simply can't get my search activity to start.

I have a main activity, from which I want the search button to start a search activity:

file `MainApp.java`

```
public class MainApp extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mainapplayout);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m){
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainappmenu,m);
      return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem m) {
      if(m.getItemId()==R.id.menu_search){
        return onSearchRequested(); // THIS IS CALLED, AND RETURNS TRUE
      }else return false;
    }
}
```

Neither pressing the UI button, nor the hardware search key, invokes the search. 
`onSearchRequested()` is definitely called, and returns `true`.

file `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="org.homphysiology.lists"
 android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"  
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application 
             android:name="org.homphysiology.lists.MainApp"
                  ****REMOVED THIS LINE NOW, thanks arju, still not working tho
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="org.homphysiology.lists.MainApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="org.homphysiology.lists.SearchActivity"
        />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.homphysiology.lists.SearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 ****REMOVED THIS LINE NOW, thanks tushar, still not working tho
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"
        />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and I have the following:

File `res/xml/searchable.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schamas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:label="@string/search_label"
  android:hint="@string/search_hint"
/>
```

These strings are in `/res/values/strings.xml`.

The search activity itself is simple, but is **never created** - I have a breakpoint in the constructor:

file `SearchActivity.java`:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setListAdapter(...)
  }
}
```

Can anyone spot any problem here?
[compiling in eclipse Juno 4.2.1, SDK 21.0.1, testing on HTC desire Z]
Thanks...

---

### ADDENDUM

```
((SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE))
  .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())
```

returns `null`. Maybe this is just hammering home the fact that my `SearchActivity` hasn't been registered properly...

---

Modifying @arju's suggestion: I can start the Search activity "manually" by using

```
boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem m){
   startActivity(new Intent(this,SearchActivity.class));  
   return true;
}
```

but of course, this won't work with the hardware button, and moreover, it doesn't display the system search dialog.

---

I have also tried setting the search metadata for the whole application as opposed to the main activity:

```
<manifest>
  <application>
     <activity ...MainApp...        >  ...  </activity>
     <activity ...SearchActivity... >  ...  </activity>
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
         android:value="org.homphysiology.lists.SearchActivity"
     />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

same problem! search activity is never instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android documentation says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#DeclaringSearchableActivity):

> Note: The < intent-filter> does not need a < category> with the DEFAULT value (which you usually see in < activity> elements), because the system delivers the ACTION_SEARCH intent explicitly to your searchable activity, using its component name.

EDIT:

It's this:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schamas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

should be:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Notice `schamas` vs `schemas` :)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried removing the `<category name=DEFAULT>`. No luck! same problem, nothing happens on search button, and nothing in **LOGCAT** either.

Comment: Are you doing logging in onCreate of your `SearchActivity` or just using a breakpoint? Can you try logging just to be certain?

Comment: OK have tried doing logs everywhere, it definitely calls `onSearchRequested()` of the `MainApp`, but never instantiates the `SearchActivity` class... mystery?

Comment: @SanjayManohar Can you join this discussion in the chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26799/help-sanjay

Comment: Thank you so much @Tushar, that was it! just 'schema'. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Intent i=new Intent("android.intent.action.SEARCH");

startActivity(i);

Comment: Thanks!. OK I have removed that property now. But same problem! not launching search...

Comment: What is your exact problem can u tell as simple

Comment: The application executes fine. I want the `SearchActivity` to launch when either the menu option is selected, or the hardware search key is pressed. At the moment, absolutely nothing happens in both cases. :-(

Comment: onsearchrequsted() is that method you want to execute? u r saying its executing fine and returning true . can u post the code for that method.

Comment: I haven't touched the default `onSearchRequested()`. I believe it's part of `android.app.Activity`, and it's supposed to create the default search dialog specified in the manifest? The docs say it will return `true` if the search dialog is created (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29). But my `SearchActivity` isn't created!

Comment: This code `Intent("android.intent.action.SEARCH");` brings up a menu for searching lots of other apps installed on the phone. But using your technique I was able to instantiate my own `SearchActivity` manually (see edit to main post). Unfortunately this method can't bring up a search dialog...